# how to change the display position of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have seen many demos of the jqgrid and all show the grid at the top left corner of the browser. 
I need to display it in different locations hopefully within my own divs but I can not get it to work no matter what I try. I have read it gets wrapped into other div so I even tried to move them unsucessfully.

Example:

```
<div id='draggable2' style='position:absolute; top:100; left:500; background:blue'>
  <table id="list2" class='scroll' style='position:absolute; top:100; left:100'>
    <tr><td/></tr>
  </table> 
  <div id="pager" style='background:cyan'></div>
</div>
```

Then in loadComplete: function

```
$('#list2').attr('left','100px');
$('#list2').attr('top','100px');
$('#draggable2').attr('left','100px');
$('#draggable2').attr('top','100px');
$('#gview_list2').attr('left','100px');
$('#gview_list2').attr('top','100px');
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

has nothing to do with jqgrid. You don't need the jQuery to modify. You forgot your units in the html. 100 what? Change "top:100" to "top:100px" and the initial position works just fine.

you can toy with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cszkE/2/

just change the style values then hit 'run'

Comment: ah! just started using it recently. Thanks for the tip.